# Can I control how many events will be shown on the fly in fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using full calendar for our application. The thing I want to do is to control how many events are displayed in calendar on the fly. 
I know that eventLimitClick is an eventHandler for + more, initially I just want to show 3 events by default for a day, but once a user clicks + more, I want it to display whole events in a calendar. 
So, I adjusted config.views.month.eventLimit on the fly and then I tried to rerender calendar but it does not work properly. Has anyone achieve this issue in full calendar? Could you please give help about this?

Comment: please show us what you tried, in case we can fix it for you.

Comment: I am sorry for late response, I was able to fix it, I wanted to rerender calendar after adjusting eventLimit, I was able to do it by calendar.FullCalendar('destroy'). Thank you so much for your concern.